# Rails delayed_job sending email as HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, encoding, delayed-job

Using delayed_job to send emails- files are filename.text.html.erb

Sometimes they show up in my inbox rendered properly and sometimes they show up as HTML code.

I notice that when I stop and start the delayed_job daemon on the server, it seems to help in some cases but not all the time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In your mailer class, you need to set `content_type` to `text/html` or `text/plain`. The code looks something like this:

```
class Postman < ActionMailer::Base
  # ...
  def foo_mail
    content_type 'text/html'
    # code
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```